# Feed me plugin craft\commerce\services\ProductTypes::hasPermission(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type craft\elements\User

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-feedme

Whenever I run a feed via the Direct link eg. [https://site.com/index.php?p=actions/feed-me/feeds/run-task&direct=1&feedId=[id]&passkey=[passkey]](https://site.com/index.php?p=actions/feed-me/feeds/run-task&direct=1&feedId=%5Bid%5D&passkey=%5Bpasskey%5D) when I'm logged out of the CP.

I get the following error:

```
craft\commerce\services\ProductTypes::hasPermission(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type craft\elements\User, null given, called in /public_html/vendor/craftcms/commerce/src/services/ProductTypes.php on line 178
```

When logged in, it works fine

**Steps to reproduce**

Log out of CP
Run a feed via the Direct link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Commerce that has been fixed via https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/commit/b3ec7bb0d21f461df7a3297fbc74c295a5e1fc82 and will be included in the next Commerce 3 and 4 releases.